# Reset jQuery DataTables to default

Tags: jquery, datatables

Using jQuery [DataTables](http://datatables.net/index), we need to reset table's columns width, their visibility and current pagination number to default and reload it again. How is it possible to clean its cookie, data and reload it?

Comment: Would you be more specific about those methods?

Comment: Would you be more specific about your question?

Answer (score 1):

As you havent provided any code to start with i m giving you my code you can custom fit in your requirement. I think you are getting data with ajax. If so you can use this.

```
var resultexist=false; // Initialize status variable
var reportjqdt=null; // Data Table reference


function populateReportData (result) { // Result is an arry of data
var headers=result.arrh;
var data=result.arr;
var dataType=result.arrDT;

var $resultdiv = $("#repResult");
var hdrfdr="<tr>";


for(var i=0;i<headers.length;i++) {
hdrfdr+="<th>"+headers[i]+"</th>";
}
hdrfdr+="</tr>";


var tbldata="<tbody>";
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
if(i%headers.length==0 ){
tbldata+="<tr>";
}
    tbldata+="<td class="+(i%(2*headers.length)==0?"odd":"even")+" >"+data[i]+"</td>";
if((i+1)%headers.length==0 ){
tbldata+="</tr>";
}
}
tbldata+="</tbody>";

var table="<table id='reportDataTBL' > <thead>"+ hdrfdr + "</thead>"+ tbldata + "<tfoot>"+hdrfdr+"</tfoot></table>";



if(resultexist){
reportjqdt.fnDestroy();  // Delete if datatable exists
}
$resultdiv.html(table);

reportjqdt =  $('#reportDataTBL').dataTable({"bJQueryUI": true});
resultexist=true;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but `fnDestroy()` didn't work for me. I tried to manually remove header's width and reset their visibility and then called save state method, again.

Comment: actually without having your code i cannt give you exact solution. so if it helped and you solved then ok.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with jQuery DataTables, but looking at the documentation you can try a couple of things:

Destroy the table and rebuild it:

```
 TableVariable.fnDestroy();
 TableVariable.fnDraw();
```

Try the fnDraw function without destroying it, it should redraw the table:

```
TableVariable.fnDraw();
```

In these examples, TableVariable is the variable you have used to initialize the DataTable, like so:

```
var TableVariable = $(".table").dataTable();
```

Goodluck

Answer (score 0):

Normally it should work with

```
var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
oTable.fnDraw();
```

But, since you are telling it is not then you should simply consider deleting the table and then try calling the same method which you used to create the table in the first place. This way the table will be re-created without any previous settings.

Since, everything happens on the client side, you may not notice much difference.

Comment: We save column's size and visibility on the database, too. I couldn't find any help but people who mention `fnDestroy()` help me a lot to add a custom method. Using `fnDestroy()` didn't help me and it destroys the UI but not cleaning the cookie nor resetting to default.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a bug in `fnDestroy()` or we're using this component not in a proper way.

Comment: Check your dataTable initialization and default options as well. You can tweak them and try it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 //init dataTable
 function loadDataTable()
 {
   table = $("#table").dataTable({ ... });
 }

 // Reset dataTable
function resetFilter()
 {
  // Clear table state
  table.state.clear();
  // Destroy table state
  table.destroy();
  // Reload dataTable without reload the page
  loadDataTable();
 }
```

Enjoy.